# On C++ run program if correct otherwise ask input again

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm new into programing. I'm working on a program that will tell the odd and even numbers that are less or equal to the user's input (for inputs >=0). How do I make the program run if value is >=0 and ask for the input again if the value is <0. 
Here is the program:

```
> #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Please enter only a positive value\n";
    // Get number from user
    int input = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number:\n";
    cin >> input;
    int number = 1;
    while (input >= 0 && number <= input) {
        // Print some numbers
        cout << "Here are some odd numbers:\n";
        while (number <= input) {
            cout << number << endl;
            number = number + 2;
        }
        // Print some numbers
        cout << "Here are some even numbers:\n";
        int number2 = 0;
        while (number2 <= input) {
            cout << number2 << endl;
            number2 = number2 + 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a while loop.  Loop until the user meets the criteria for good input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Please enter only a positive value\n";
    // Get number from user
    int input = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number:\n";
    cin >> input;
    while (input < 0) {
        cout << "Input is negative. Enter again: \n";
        cin >> input;
    }
    int number = 1;
    while (input >= 0 && number <= input) {
        // Print some numbers
        cout << "Here are some odd numbers:\n";
        while (number <= input) {
            cout << number << endl;
            number = number + 2;
        }
        // Print some numbers
        cout << "Here are some even numbers:\n";
        int number2 = 0;
        while (number2 <= input) {
            cout << number2 << endl;
            number2 = number2 + 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I added this chunk:

```
while (input < 0) {
     cout << "Input is negative. Enter again: \n";
     cin >> input;
}
```

to handle negative inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (input < 0)
{
    cout << "Enter a number:\n";
    cin >> input;
    if (input < 0) 
        // Here you can print something to tell that input was not correct
}
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.